# centos,django, mod_wsgi & different python installations

Tags: centos, python, django, mod-wsgi

I am getting this error

`File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module`

`TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named django_bcrypt`.

`django_bcrypt` is installed and can be imported at python shell.

`django_bcrypt` is installed at `/root/src/django_bcrypt`

Also I have an old python 2.4 `/usr/bin/python2.4`

And my new one is `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`

I also have one `/usr/local/bin/python`

I checked the sys.path,sys.prefix,sys.version using a wsgi script.Everything is correct.

First i was having an error `import site failed` error.I corrected it by adding WSGIPythonHome `/usr/local`

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your Python path set?  By default, `/root/src` won't be in your `PYTHONPATH`, so you'll either need to install it into your site packages (recommended!), or add this path to your `PYTHONPATH` variable.  See the [mod_wsgi documentation](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments) for how to do this.

Comment: Apache/mod_wsgi will never see your PYTHONPATH variable. Append directory to sys.path in WSGI script file instead.

Comment: I tried that,still same error.Help please.

Comment: Have you made sure that user that Apache runs your code as can even read the directory the module is in as well as all the code files. If you have restrictive permissions on directory it will not be able to access them. The /root directory may even be owned by root with no access to anyone else and so no way Apache user can read it.

Comment: Graham, could it also be possible that he compiled mod_wsgi against a different version of Python than the one he's trying to run the script with?

Comment: Possibly, but his initial error of import site failed is consistent with what will happen when it is built properly against a Python in non standard location. That is, it will see /usr/bin/python and think therefore that Python 2.7 is under /usr when it isn't and so they had to use WSGIPythonHome so that it knew 2.7 was actually under /usr/local. If it was built against different Python version under /usr, wouldn't have expected it to get the import site failed message. So, on face value doesn't look like that sort of conflict.